# Using dns_check in salt (wherein the documention seems wrong)

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

The [saltstack docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#dns-check) note the existence of the `dns_check` jinja filter in 2017.7.3:

```
{{ 'www.google.com' | dns_check }}
```

which should return an ip4v address as a string.

But when I try it:

```
test_this_one:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        echo {{ 'www.google.com' | dns_check }}
```

I instead see

```
local:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:firewall' failed: Jinja error: dns_check() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 418, in render_jinja_tmpl
    output = template.render(**decoded_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 42, in top-level template code
TypeError: dns_check() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Am I missing something?  I'm inclined to believe I've made a mistake rather than that the docs are so publicly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code it looks like `dns_check` now takes a `port` argument - the docstring says:

> Tries to connect to the address before considering it useful. If no address can be reached, the first one resolved is used as a fallback.

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/06a00be0e1f06399805e19261e4d00f6cfd9c6a0/salt/utils/network.py#L1750

So it's probably enough to put any port in here and it should work. (and perhaps an issue should be raised about making port optional?)

Comment: Yes, that's it.  The documentation is incorrect.  It suffices to say ` {{ 'www.google.com' | dns_check(port='443') }}`, for example.  But this is a bit rubbish, since the name (check dns) is not what it is doing (check connectable).  I'll file issues.  Thanks!

Comment: Issue filed [here - #46053](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/46053)